# Does the PWM generated by the 555 make sense in this circuit?

Tags: led, pwm, triac

This circuit I doubt very much that it works with the led lamp since it is not a linear load.

But assuming that I replace it with an incandescent lamp, with the first logical 0 to 1 edge of the PWM occurring, the TRIAC will activate and will remain conducting until the AC voltage drops to zero volts, that is, the following pulses of the PWM signal they will have no effect on TRIAC.

Am I rigth?

[image]

[Circuit description](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/dimmer-circuit-for-led-bulbs/?unapproved=100744&moderation-hash=e352484a0a57dcbc4066020190c6d117#comment-100744)

Comment: AC voltage does not stay at zero volts

Comment: Sinusoidal voltage, in a moment it goes through zero volts periodically

Comment: you are not understanding my comment ... `the following pulses of the PWM signal they will have no effect on TRIAC` implies that the AC voltage stays at zero volts

Comment: I'm pretty sure the circuit in general doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this circuit is supposed to do. It's certainly not a practical dimmer. Maybe it's intended to cause some modulation of the light from the beat frequencies of the 555 and the mains. It's hit and miss over any given half cycle whether you'll get the triac to turn on or not, but only integral half cycles get passed. Or maybe someone just stuck two or three circuits together without any understanding of the output components and without testing. It is the internet, after all.

The zero-crossing detector in the MOC3061 will not allow the triac to trigger until the abs value of the mains voltage is less than about 12V. The triac will not turn off until the current drops below the holding current (a few mA). There is no synchronization of the relatively high PWM frequency with the mains except what happens accidentally as a result of ripple on the transformerless power supply.